# I am trying to create an array of objects from my class "Cerc",which has a property of type int and one of type string

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

       //raza of type integer
       //nume of type String

    System.out.print("Dimension is = " );
    int n=scan.nextInt();
    Cerc c[]=new Cerc[n]; //array of objects



    //init array
        for (int i = 0; i <c.length ; i++) {
            c[i]=new Cerc();

            System.out.print("Raza=");
            c[i].raza=scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Nume=");
            c[i].nume=scan.nextLine();

        //Printing array
        for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
            c[i].afisare(); 
        }
    }*main*
}*class*
```

Can someone explain me how to initialize arrays of objects who have parameters of different types using user input from keyboard.

Comment: Can you describe the issue better? Maybe this: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: Also, it looks like you are missing a `}` after the first `for`.

Comment: Scanner was not able of reading int and String of that object,this was the issue in my opinion. Maybe you could help me understand more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create appropriate constructor(s) and/or setters and getters. Given below is an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    double salary;

    Person(String name, int age, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        Person persons[] = null;
        System.out.print("Enter dimension: ");
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            persons = new Person[n]; // array of objects

            // init array
            for (int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter name: ");
                String name = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter age: ");
                int age = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Enter salary: ");
                double salary = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
                persons[i] = new Person(name, age, salary);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
        // Printing array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(persons[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter dimension: 2
Enter name: John
Enter age: 23
Enter salary: 1234
Enter name: Sam
Enter age: 34
Enter salary: 4321
Person [name=John, age=23, salary=1234.0]
Person [name=Sam, age=34, salary=4321.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

read...() will stop either at the first whitespace character or at `\n`. After calling readInt() on a line that has only one int (that the scanner already read), calling readLine() will return what's remaining on the line(in this case only whitespace).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

        //raza of type integer
        //nume of type String
        System.out.print("Dimension is = " );
        // The replaceAll("[^\\d]+", "") removes all characters that aren't digits
        int n=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine().replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""));
        // Arrays of objects are declared like this:
        Cerc[] c = new Cerc[n]; //array of objects

        //init array
        for (int i = 0; i <c.length ; i++) {
            c[i]=new Cerc();

            System.out.print("Raza=");
            // The replaceAll("[^\\d]+", "") removes all characters that aren't digits
            c[i].raza = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine().replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""));
            System.out.print("Nume=");
            c[i].nume = scan.nextLine();
        }
        //Printing array
        for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
            c[i].afisare(); 
        }
    }
}
```